# How to display the default values in datagridview for multiple rows

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview in a windows form,i have to display 5 rows with data.

i am using this code...

```
private void DGV_ActivityDtls_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{        
   e.Row.Cells[0].Value = "Activities";
   e.Row.Cells[1].Value = " ";
   e.Row.Cells[2].Value = "LT";
}
```

for one row it is working fine but i have 4 more rows .
i am new to this can any one please help me ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DefaultValuesNeeded` is fired only when a new default row is created by user or `DataGridView` (see more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultvaluesneeded.aspx))

For your purpose when you are dynamically creating 5 rows use `RowsAdded` event

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == -1 || e.RowCount == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < e.RowCount; i++)
    {
        var index = e.RowIndex + i;

        var row = DGV_ActivityDtls.Rows[index];
        row.Cells[0].Value = "Activities";
        row.Cells[1].Value = " ";
        row.Cells[2].Value = "LT";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gzaxx..i am having 4 more rows to display.. how can i display them ?

Comment: I do not understand, you want to show them? Then change `row.Visible = true;` if they are hidden.

Comment: I MEAN WHEN I OPENED THE SCREEN THAT CONTAINS DATAGRIDVIEW THEN DATAGRIDVIEW SHOULD BE FILLED WITH THE FOLLOWING DATA..

ACTIVITIES   --   LT,
FUEL       --      UNIT,
BATTERY DEFIECIENCY   -- UNIT,
MECHANICAL ASST    -- UNIT,
STARTING FLUID   -- UNIT,

Comment: You can fill those rows with data in place were you are creating them.

Comment: how can i fill multiple rows?

Pls help

Comment: Can you edit you original post and show the code you use to INSERT those 5 rows to `DataGridView`?

Comment: sorry gzaxx i am not having idea for that. for 1 row the above code is working but for 5 rows i dont know how to display when application starts.